# How to toggle checkbox on slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple **JQuery Ui** slider that contains hidden checkbox inside. I need to add the ability to toggle slider and thus change checkbox value.

How can I do this?

[Codepen example.](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/RRVKwP)

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin-top: 50px"></div>

<div class="col-md-1">
  <div id="slider">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      step : 99,
      animate : 'slow'
    });
  });
```

[image]

Comment: What action or when should this box become checked?

Comment: @Twisty When I move slider to the right checkbox should become checked. Like on the picture in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to exam the value when the slider stops. This can be done like so:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
      step: 99,
      animate: 'slow',
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.value > 0) {
          $("#slider input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

The `value` will be either 0 or 100. So when the slider is to the right, it's at 100% value or some value. It will be more than 0, so that's what we check for.

See more about this event function: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop

Comment: Can we uncheck the checkbox when we are moving slider back?

Comment: @BillyLogan yes, I would switch it to `if(ui.value === 0) { $("#slider input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false); } else { $("#slider input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can check and uncheck by moving the slide like this

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      animate : 'slow',
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value > 0){
          $("#slider input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $("#slider input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```